# Plus sign breaks regex validation

Tags: python, regex, validation

I have numerous regular expressions, such as:

```
quantity_validation = re.compile("""^-?[0-9]+$""", re.I)
```

I use these regex in functions like:

```
def validate_quantity(self, value):
    if value != self.context.quantity:
        # while not self.quantity_validation.match(value):
        #     return 0, "Value is not a number"
        if not self.quantity_validation.match(value):
            return 0, "Value is not a number"
    return 1, ""
```

and the validation method:

```
@view_config(name="validate", renderer='json')
def validate(self, full={}):
    def do_validation(field, value):
        message = ""
        valid = 1
        if getattr(self, 'validate_%s' % field, False):
            valid, message = getattr(self, 'validate_%s' % field)(value)

        out = dict(message=message, valid=valid, value=value)
        return out
    if not full:
        field = self.request.params.get('field')
        if not field:
            return "INVALID"
        return do_validation(field, self.request.params.get('value'))
    else:
        return dict(((field, do_validation(field, value)) for field, value in full.items()))
```

On the HTML form I have a modal with a `quantity` field on which I do ajax validation(I use jqBootstrapValidation to validate my forms)

The regex validation works fine until I type a `+` then the validation stop working until I refresh the page.

Why does the validation stop working?
Is it perhaps a bug in jqBootstrapValidation?
or is it a bug in the [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

Comment: What is your real problem? The regex seems fine to me: http://pastebin.com/9K32sfaA

Comment: I am not saying there is a problem with the regex itself, I am saying that there is a problem with the validion with the regex. Will it help if I include screen shots of the problem?

Comment: It is *exceedingly* unlikely that this is a bug in the `re` module. Have you tested the `validate` view in isolation? Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: What do you mean by *"stop working until I refresh the page."*? The validation looks correct... Have you done some units tests on validations methods, as Martijn suggested?

Comment: @Martijn I got no errors in the console, though I noticed that when I type the `+` the ajax stop working, i.e: `http://localhost:6543/stock/orders/new/validate?value=+&field=quantity` notice the `value=+` part of the url. That is the last `GET` request I get.

Comment: @Maxime The ajax requests stop running as I have exlained in my response to Martijns` question.

Comment: That's a space, not a plus; plus is encoded to `%2B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not encoding your URLs/inputs correctly.  The `'+'` gets parsed into a `' '` when you pass it via the parameter string.  Try `'%2B'` instead which should be decoded into a `'+'` through the form library.

Comment: any suggestion on how I can encode the `+` inline? i.e. `<input type="text" id="order-quantity-field" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" required data-validation-ajax-ajax="{{'stock.orders.new.validate'|route_path}}">`. The `data-validation-ajax-ajax="{{'stock.orders.new.validate'|route_path}}"` part sends the ajax request, so is there a way that I can do this inline using something like `encodeURI()`?`encodeURI` does not escape the `+` however, so what would I use to escape it?

Comment: Are you sending the validation logic to the client side and then push that back to the server?  That looks woefully unsafe to me.  Anyway, in python2 you would use `urllib.quote`, python3 `urllib.parse.quote`.